# simple question about meaning of "census"

Tags: survey, census

A text defines "census" as a survey of the entire population and "sample" as a survey of part of the population.
But the text also claims the US Census is an example of a census.
It seems to me the US Census is actually an example of a sample not a census because not every person fills out a survey.
Is that correct or am I missing something?

Comment: The United States Census Bureau surveys all households in the United States every ten years to get a complete count of all U.S. citizens. When some households don't respond individuals are sent personally to the homes to get the count.

Comment: The US Census attempts to be a census, but for practical reasons it falls a little short and must impute some missing values.  I sympathize with this: I believe that I am a living person, even though some small parts of me have been lost or replaced by non-biological materials.